# How to reorder upload files in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angular-ui-sortable

I am using AngularJS and `ui-sortable` to reorder images to be uploaded via HTML using the following input:

```
<input name="userfile[]" type="file" id="userfile" ng-if="charSelected" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().filesLoaded(this.files)" multiple>
```

I display the images grabbed from file upload as follows:

```
<table>
    <tr><span ng-if="charSelected && type == 'Image'">Preview (Drag to Reorder)</span></tr>
    <tr ng-model="images" ui-sortable="reorderFiles">
        <td ng-repeat="image in images track by $index" ng-if="charSelected && type == 'Image'"><img ng-src="{{image}}" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I can drag and drop to reorder the images just fine. However, the problem is, I don't know how to change the order of the files when a user reorders them. I tried the following:

```
// Sortable change event
$scope.reorderFiles = {
    update: function(e, ui) {
        var originalPos = ui.item.index();
        var newPos = ui.item.sortable.dropindex;
        // Swap the files
        var t1 = document.getElementById('userfile').files[originalPos];
        console.log("orig: " + document.getElementById('userfile').files[originalPos].name);
        document.getElementById('userfile').files[originalPos] = document.getElementById('userfile').files[newPos];
        document.getElementById('userfile').files[newPos] = t1;
        console.log("new: " + document.getElementById('userfile').files[originalPos].name);
    }
}
```

But it seems the object returned by document.getElementById is immutable, because console.log just returns the same name even after I swap files[originalPos] with files[newPos].

How can I change the order of the files the user wants to upload?

Comment: You cannot set the file attribute for security reasons.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/266087

Comment: I see. So I'd probably need to do something like make an array of indices to pass in the POST data so the server-side can handle it?

Comment: Well, accessing the array of files from javascript (i believe) only returns you the string of the filename. I don't think it actually returns you the file. Your best bet is to just send it as is, and then do the necessary ordering/shuffling on the server side

Comment: Edit: Misread your comment. Yes, that would be the solution